# Mathematica 8.0, obvious simplification missed, why?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, simplify

I apologize beforehand if there’s an obvious answer, I’m not a user of Mathematica but I’m working on a borrowed laptop and that’s what I have available for the moment.
For some reason `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` are missing obvious simplifications, for instance:

```
Simplify[1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + 2/3 z)]
```

Yields:

```
1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + (2 z)/3)
```

For some reason, it doesn't get rid of the 1/2 factor, try it yourself!

Of course I can do it manually but I have much bigger expressions with the same problem.

Am I missing something?

PS: This laptop has Mathematica 8.0

**EDIT**: `FullSimplify` works for the previous example but it doesn't for

```
FullSimplify[1/2 (2 (x - y)^2 + 2/5 (y - z)^2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

`FullSimplify` works for me:

```
In[693]:= Simplify[1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + 2/3 z)]

Out[693]= 1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + (2 z)/3)

In[694]:= FullSimplify[1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + 2/3 z)]

Out[694]= 1/5 (x - y)^2 + z/3

In[695]:= $Version

Out[695]= "8.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 5, 2011)"
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why `Simplify` misses this case, but `FullSimplify` helps out here:

```
FullSimplify[1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + 2/3 z)]
```

gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `Collect` can be more appropriate :

```
 In[1]:= Collect[1/2 (2/5 (x - y)^2 + 2/3 z), {z}]

 Out[1]= 1/5 (x - y)^2 + z/3
```

**Edit**

```
In[2]:= Collect[1/2 (2 (x - y)^2 + 2/5 (y - z)^2), {x - y, y - z}]

Out[2]= (x - y)^2 + 1/5 (y - z)^2
```

In this specific case Verbeia's approach using `Ditribute` seems to be the simplest way to get what you want, however `Collect[expr, list]` is customizable to generic cases by ordering a list. In Mathematica there are many functions, which may help in various cases. Though `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` could be a bit smarter they can do quite a lot. A nice example of their different behavior you may find beneath:

[image]

I recommend to take a closer look at a neat demonstration what one may expect in general  : [Simplifying Some Algebraic Expressions Using Mathematica](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SimplifyingSomeAlgebraicExpressionsUsingMathematica/).

Answer (score 2):

For your second example, `Distribute` works:

```
Distribute[1/2 (2 (x - y)^2 + 2/5 (y - z)^2)]
```

results in

```
  (x - y)^2 + 1/5 (y - z)^2
```

which is what I assume you want.